# Problema con api en nodejs y pm2

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, sequelize, pm2

Tengo una api creada en nodejs con express y sequelize, funciona bien de manera local, pero cuando la desplegué a producción con pm2, no funciona, ¿qué puedo hacer?
Dejo la parte del código que no funciona correctamente

```
//Registro de nueva persona
    signUp(req, res) {
        persona.create({
            curp: req.body.curp,
            rfc: req.body.rfc,
            nss: req.body.nss,
            nombre: req.body.nombre,
            apellido_paterno: req.body.apellido_paterno,
            apellido_materno: req.body.apellido_materno,
            fecha_nacimiento: req.body.fecha_nacimiento,
            email: req.body.email,
            genero: req.body.genero,
            estado_civil: req.body.estado_civil,
            tipo_sangre: req.body.tipo_sangre,
            status: req.body.status,
            requiere_actualizar_domicilio: req.body.requiere_actualizar_domicilio,
            requiere_actualizar_bachilletato: req.body.requiere_actualizar_bachillerato,
            requiere_actualizar_contacto: req.body.requiere_actualizar_contacto,
            requiere_actualizar_contacto_personal: req.body.requiere_actualizar_contacto_personal,
            rh_actualizacion: req.body.rh_actualizacion,
        }).then(persona => {
            let token =jwt.sign({ persona: persona}, authconfig.secret, { 
                expiresIn: authconfig.expires
            });
//Crear usuario
            alumno.count({
                col: 'control',
            }).then(function (count) {
                function llenarConCeros(num, totalLength) {
                    return String(num).padStart(totalLength, '0');
                }
                var now = new Date();
                var fecha_control = (now.getFullYear() + "7O").slice(2);
                function randomStr(len, arr) {
                    var ans = '';
                    for (var i = len; i > 0; i--) {
                        ans +=
                        arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
                    }
                    return ans;
                } 
                const folio_control = llenarConCeros(count, 5);
                n_control = fecha_control + folio_control;
                alumno.create({
                    control: n_control,
                    alupas: randomStr(10, '123456789ABCDEFGHI'),
                    persona_id: persona.id,
                })
            })
//Cierra creación de usuario
            res.json({
                persona: persona,
                token: token,
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json(err)
        })
    },
```

No sé si es problema del código, de apache o de la base de datos (mysql), el servidor al hacer la petición hace el recorrido hasta crear la persona, pero se salta la generación del token y la creación del alumno.
Editado: el problema es parte de jwt, sigo sin saber cuál es el problema, pero sin esa parte, el código funciona normalmente pero al menos ya reduje el problema a esa parte

Comment: Si "se salta" la generacion del token y la creacion del usuario es porque está entrando en el catch... que error te sale en el catch?

Comment: Solo me manda un 500, igual hice que el catch me mandara el error directamente a consola, sin status y me da igual 500

Comment: Tienes que debugear entonces en el servidor... error 500 es error en el servidor

Comment: Estuve haciendo investigación y al parecer es problema con jwt, algo respecto a los heathers o algo así, igual no he encontrado mucha información al respecto (mis pruebas han sido con postman), muchas gracias por contestar y tomarte el tiempo de leer :)

Comment: Los "headers", seguro debes mandar o estás enviando mal algún header de autorización

Comment: efectivamente, son los headers, llevo un buen rato investigando al respecto y nada más no entiendo cómo implementarlo

Comment: El problema es que sin mas información no te podemos ayudar... toca que revises como funciona tu sistema de authenticacion en el backend y según eso ajustes el código. También deberias poner "logs" en el servidor para ver que pistas puedes encontrar y saber exactamente donde está el problema